# How to find clientID of Datalist control using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a DataList with a ModalPopupExtender control. When I click the div in datalist show ModalPopupExtender .

```
<asp:DataList ID="AdsDataList" runat="server" RepeatColumns="4" 
               RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
   <ItemTemplate>
     <div class="Detail_Content" id="detailcontact" runat="server" 
          onclick="return OpenPopup();">
        <label><%# Eval("Name") %></label>
     </div>
     <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" Style="display: none;">
         <div class="popup_block" style="width: 550px;left:30%;top:100px">
              <label><%# Eval("FatherCategoryName")                                
         </div>
     </asp:Panel>
        <cc1:ModalPopupExtender runat="server" ID="ModalPopupExtender1" 
             TargetControlID="detailcontact" PopupControlID="Panel2" 
             PopupDragHandleControlID="header" DropShadow="false" 
             RepositionMode="RepositionOnWindowResizeAndScroll" X="400" Y="130" 
             BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"CancelControlID="btnclose1" />
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

I want, when user click to background, hide ModalPopupExtender .

I use this jquery code. but don't find ModalPopupExtender .

```
var modalWindow = $("[id*=AdsDataList] [id*=ModalPopupExtender1]");
```

and

```
$find('#<%= AdsDataList.FindControl("ModalPopupExtender1").ClientID %>');
```

but get error

> 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

How to find clientID of Datalist control using jquery?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried getting it directly... if the id is unique ..this shuld work in your case

```
 var modalWindow = $("#ModalPopupExtender1]");
 ......
```

Comment: Thanks, but when i use it. I get error 'The name 'ModalPopupExtender1' does not exist in the current context'

Answer (score 0):

You can take benefit of sibling selector of jQuery.
As `Panel` render as `div` and it is very next to the `div` you are clicking.

```
   function OpenPopup() {
       $(this).next("div").show();
   }
```

Or put some `css` class on both your `div` and `panel` and you can use jquery as below

```
     $(".divClass").click(function() {
        $(this).next("div.pannelclass").show();
   });
```

Where .divClass is a cssclass of you `div` and `pannelclass` is a cssclass of your panel.

jQuery selector detail
http://api.jquery.com/next/

### Edit-1

```
<ItemTemplate>
 <div class="Detail_Content" id="detailcontact" runat="server" >
    <label><%# Eval("Name") %></label>
 </div>
 <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" CssClass='panelclass' runat="server" Style="display: none;">
     <div class="popup_block" style="width: 550px;left:30%;top:100px">
          <label><%# Eval("FatherCategoryName")                                
     </div>
 </asp:Panel>
    <cc1:ModalPopupExtender runat="server" ID="ModalPopupExtender1" 
         TargetControlID="detailcontact" PopupControlID="Panel2" 
         PopupDragHandleControlID="header" DropShadow="false" 
         RepositionMode="RepositionOnWindowResizeAndScroll" X="400" Y="130" 
         BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"CancelControlID="btnclose1" />
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

### jQuery

```
   $(".Detail_Content").click(function(event) {
        $(this).next("div.panelclass").show();
        event.preventDefault()
        return false;
   });
```

### Edit 2

Links to hide model popup

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165083/Tips-Tricks-Hide-popup-on-background-click
http://forums.asp.net/t/1369095.aspx/1

Comment: Thanks, I use this code and add a alert() to code, but don't run it when click div.

Comment: have you add `css-class` on both panel and your div?

Comment: Thanks a lot, How to hide ModalPopupExtender1 when click background.

Comment: Thnaks a lot, I use this code before, but when i have a popup in datalist, how to find '_backgroundElement' and add handler in Edit-1 code?!!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to locate the control by just calling the following without JQuery.

```
var dataListControl = document.getElementById('<%:AdsDataList.ClientID%>')
```

With JQuery

```
var dataListControl = $find('<%:AdsDataList.ClientID%>')
```

or

```
var dataListControl = $('<%: AdsDataList.ClientID%>')
```

Comment: Thanks, but i want find clientid of controls in datalist.

Answer (score 0):

```
   try this....if model id is unique

   var model =  $("[id$=ModalPopupExtender1]")

    or if not unique then use...

    OpenPopup(this) ...

    function (ob)
    {
    var e = $(this).parent().find("div#ModalPopupExtender1");
    }
```

Comment: Thnaks a lot, but how to find ModalPopupExtender1_backgroundElement ?

Comment: what is backgroundElement  ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code when you click on any template in datalist

```
function (e) {

            var ModalPopupExtender1= $(this).closest('tr').find('#<%=ModalPopupExtender1.ClientID %>');
            e.preventDefault();
        });
```